# How to add claims identity to the "ClaimsPrincipal User" of razor PageModel with claims from "external login"

Tags: razor, jwt, identity, razor-pages

On post of our razor page, we call to an Api method to sign in users, and this Api method returns a JTW with some claims. After login has been succeed, we try put this claims on `User` property of `PageModel` base class, but when we try access this claims on another page, this claims isn't available anymore.

[image: User property from PageModel]

***Approach:***

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var jwtToken = await _externalApi.Execute<string>($"/auth/", Method.POST, jsonBody: myCredentialsObject);

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var securityToken = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);

    User.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(securityToken.Claims, "myClaims"));

    Response.Cookies.Append("bearer", jwtToken);

    return LocalRedirect("/user/index");

    return Page();
}
```

*SignIn page:*

[image: OnPost of SignIn page]

*Another page:*

[image: OnGet on another page]

The `User` property "is reseted" after each http request? This approach it's viable?

Comment: Do you need to add `[authorize]` on /user/index, if it needen't, you can Add Identity in /user/index. Because the scope of HttpContext is limited to the current request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, on this case, we need to create a new `ClaimsPrincipal` and "re-write" the auth cookie with `HttpContext.SignInAsync(...)` method to apply the new `ClaimsPrincipal` for  `services.AddAuthentication(...)` middleware can set the `User` property for us.

Something like that:

***Startup class:***

```
public class Startup
{
   // Omitted for brevity...
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, cookieAuthOptions =>
                {
                    cookieAuthOptions.Cookie.Name = "MyApplicationCookie";
                    cookieAuthOptions.LoginPath = "/signIn";
                    cookieAuthOptions.LogoutPath = "/signOut";
                    cookieAuthOptions.AccessDeniedPath = "/accessDenied";
                });
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
       // Omitted for brevity...
       app.UseAuthentication();
   }
}
```

***SignIn page:***

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var signinResult = await _aiguiApi.Execute<string>($"/auth/", Method.POST, jsonBody: SignInInputModel);

    var jwt = signinResult.Value.ToString();
    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    var token = handler.ReadJwtToken(jwt);

    // THIS CODE HERE, MAKE THE "MAGIC"...
    var userPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(
        new ClaimsIdentity(token.Claims, "myClaims")
    );
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(userPrincipal);
    //...

    Response.Cookies.Append("bearer", jwt);

    return LocalRedirect("/user/index");

    return Page();
}
```

[image: Set the "new Principal" of the current logged in user]

***Another page:***

[image: Another page with access to User property with "Identity" defined on SignIn method.]

That's all, folks!